# How to detect if mac os is up to date or outdated programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

Now I am working on mac osx app development.
I need to check if os is up to date or outdated programmatically.
I can see it via Software Update of System Preferences.
There are a lot of solutions to get current mac os version. But I am not interested in version. Only interested in if os is the latest one or old one.

[image]

But I want to know it in my app programmatically.
swift code or objective-c code is fine.

Comment: In the shell run `softwareupdate --list` and parse the result.

Comment: Yes, it is. But you are able to read data asynchronously from the shell with `NSTask`.

Comment: @vadian
softwareupdate --list is helpful for me

As you know, this shell command is async
$ softwareupdate --list
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
No new software available.

what I want to get as result is the messages under "Finding available software".

import SwiftShell

do {
    let command = runAsync("softwareupdate", "--list")
    try command.finish()
    let result = command.stdout.read()
    print(result)
} catch {
}

then the result is below

Software Update Tool

Finding available software

I can not get "No new software available"

Comment: @vadian
Could you provide me the code snippet getting full results of "softwareupdate --list"?

Comment: Please look at the [Ray Wenderlich Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1197-nstask-tutorial-for-os-x)

Comment: @vadian
I did it by myself. I will share my code as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is simple code snippet but I spent a lot of time to get it done.
I hope someone does not waste time like me.

```
import SwiftShell

func getIsOSXUpdate() -> Bool {
    // softwareupdate --list|tee
    let command = runAsync("softwareupdate", "--list")
    do {
        try command.finish()
    } catch {
        NSLog("could not collect available updates.")
        return false
    }

    let result = command.stdout.read()
    let error = command.stderror.read()

    if error.contains("No new software available") {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```